# Wpf MVVM models, understand the OnPropertyChanged method, can you use snippets?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have just started on a Wpf project which will use the MVVM pattern. I have made my first model, but compared to a normal web model like:

```
public string name {get;set;}
```

These models are a bit more complicated because they are implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged.

**I have created an customer model:**

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Initizalize default construcktor
    public Customer(string CustomerName)
    {
        Name = CustomerName;
    }

    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

}
```

Then I'm a bit confused, if I choose visual studio 2015 to generate a method for me, I get something like:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

What should be in the method?, can visual studio not do this for you with a snippet? like the "ctor" constructor snippet?

Hope someone can give me some tricks, to make the process a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Note the below implementation lets you call `OnPropertyChanged()` (due to the use of the `CallerMemberName` attribute in the method signature) without having to pass in the property name, which helps reduce errors and makes refactoring easier.

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Initizalize default construcktor
    public Customer(string CustomerName)
    {
        Name = CustomerName;
    }

    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected internal void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Note that it's also a common practice to create an abstract base class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` that your models will inherit. This way you don't have to implement this for every model and have a lot of redundant code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you only have to make one OnPropertyChanged method like you did here? or should you create it for all properties.

Comment: @Mikkel, just the one method.

Comment: The callerMemberName, what do you mean here?

If I call the OnPropertyChanged("Name");

What should you write inside it then?

Comment: Like my example shows, you don't have to pass anything into the `OnPropertyChanged()` method. See this link for more details on the usage of the `CallerMemberName` attribute: http://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2014/10/using-callermembername-attribute-for.html

If you're not comfortable using that, you can continue to pass the string name of your property like you're currently doing, or even use the `nameof` operator to split the difference if you're using C# 6.0.